# combining validate results in one message using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation plugin to provide a number of checks, which I may add to or remove. What would be the best way to be able to combine the outputs as one string? In the code below for password1 field I only get one message at a time, so it usually says:

'Password must be 8 characters'

or, 'Password must contain a number'

It would be nice to say, 'Password must be 8 characters. Password must contain a number. Password must contain a letter'.

I appreciate the length one is built in, but that could easily be changed to an addMethod.

Thanks.

```
<script>
jQuery.validator.addMethod("containNumber", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (/\d/.test(value));
}, "Password must contain a number");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("containUpper", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (/[A-Z]/.test(value));
}, "Password must contain an uppercase character");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("containLower", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || (/[a-z]/.test(value));
}, "Password must contain a lowercase character");

$( "#passwordchange" ).validate({
  rules: {
    password1: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 8,
      maxlength: 64,
      containNumber : true,
      containUpper: true,
      containLower: true
    },
    password2: {
        equalTo: '#password1'
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will be helpful for you

In the **`jQuery.validator.addMethod`** if anything error message comes the plugin create one `.error` class in the bottom of the input element with contain the particular error message.

what you should do is collect the all `.error` class texts iterate the error meassge and concat and display the string like the below code. put the code after you get the error class present in the dom otherwise it won't work.

```
var str = '';
$('.error').each(function() { 
   str += $(this).text() + ' '; 
});

console.log(str); // it concats all the error message
```

In html create one div like

```
<div class="concaterror"></div>
$('.error').hide(); // Hide all the error class
$('.concaterror').html(str); // append the concat error messages
```

Here hide the whole `.error` class. create one div please append the `str` variable here and display where you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will try :)

Comment: @NeilWalker - did you get any input on this